# Referring to Current View (this) in BackboneJS Events

Tags: backbone.js

I'm attempting to trigger an event when a mouse enters/exit the HTML element associated with my view in BackboneJS:

```
MyApp.Views.ListShow = Backbone.CompositeView.extend({
  tagName: 'div',

  className: 'list-show group',

  template: JST['listShow'],

  events: {
    'mouseover .list-show': 'toggleRemoveCard',
    'mouseout .list-show': 'toggleRemoveCard'
  },

  initialize: function () {
    this.listenTo(this.model, 'sync', this.render);
    this.listenTo(this.model.cards(), 'sync', this.render);
  },

  render: function () {
    var content = this.template({list: this.model});
    this.$el.html(content);
    return this;
  },

  toggleRemoveCard: function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("toggling");
    this.$('.remove-card').toggleClass('hidden');
  }

});
```

It seems that in the `events` hash, I can refer to any HTML elements that are nested inside of `.list-show`. However, how do I refer to `.list-show` itself in the events? The above way of writing the `events` doesn't seem to work; it'd be great to know why as well. Thanks!

**EDIT****:**
Turns out I just had to remove the class selector in events, and change it to

```
'mouseover': 'toggleRemoveCard',
'mouseout': 'toggleRemoveCard'
```